# Not rendering controls in debug mode

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application in which I invoke a settings window as ShowDialog on a new thread.

When I run the application in Debug mode, the settings form's Show() event does not fire. I tried the alternate Load() event and it worked. In this method, am populating a list(DataGridView) and displaying it. When the form renders, nothing shows. Its just a blank form.

However, for the same code, when I run it without debug( ctrl + F5), the Show() method is triggered and the list is displayed.

The code is part of a huge framework, so, I don't think I can provide in sufficient understandable measure.

Am using a Win7 64-bit m/c.

Also, even when I checked in spy++, it showed no contents in the form - hence it was not rendered with any controls. No code is isolated for DEBUG either.

Why does this happen and what setting might need changes?

Comment: Do you call the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke.aspx) method? You said that you are showing the dialog in a new thread, then you should call the `Invoke` method.

Comment: If you want to know what's really happening in debug mode, activate breaking on any thrown exception (in VS, select Debug->Exceptions, then in front of **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** check the box under **Thrown**). The you can see if any exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, I do use Invoke since I call this from a background thread.
I tried setting the Thrown, but it didn't throw any exceptions, just the blank form pops up. Am doing a ctrl + F5 and then attaching the process in VS. This works somehow.

Comment: Create a minimal project with the problem and upload it somewhere (on SkyDrive for example) so we can test it and investigate the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is very simple. In WinForms programming there is something called the [UI Thread](http://www.google.nl/search?q=c%23+winforms+ui+thread&oq=c%23+winforms+ui+thread). This means that all UI-related code should be executed on this thread. If you execute UI related code on a non-UI-thread, you either get a 'Cross-thread operation not valid' exception, or unexpected behaviour.

I think the solution here is to create your settings window on the UI thread instead of a new thread.

Comment: I have to use a new thread since the existing application is designed that way. Additionally, whenever UI interactions are happening, am using Invoke() and calling the delegate method.

Also, it does work fine when I run it without debug mode. The problem is occurring only when am debugging.

Could VS2010 be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, calling ShowDialog() on a new thread suggest that you really want to be calling Show() instead. That said, when the debug and release builds are executing differently, it generally means something is out of sync. No idea how or why it happens, but the fix is often as simple as clicking 'Rebuild Solution'.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I had, setting the form's `StartPosition` from `WindowsDefaultLocation` to e.g. `CenterScreen` helped.