# Form.ShowDialog() does not display window with debugging enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, testing

I've created a test within a Unit Test Project, in which I want pop up a *Form* using its `ShowDialog()` function:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestDialog()
{
  // This class inherits from Form
  TestForm serviceTestForm = new TestForm("My test form"); 
  serviceTestForm.ShowDialog();

  return;
}
```

I expect this test to reach `ShowDialog()`, and run 'indefinitely', until I close the window. However, when I run this test "with debugging", the test reaches `ShowDialog()`, and no form appears. Strangely enough, this same exact test *works* if I run "without debugging."

I need to be able to run the test "with debugging" and have the window display.

Other notes:

- `Show()` is not desirable, as it doesn't wait for the window to close to continue. (Besides... it doesn't work.)
- This same code has worked previously on another project utilizing .NET 3.5. This is only to say the `ShowDialog()` strategy has definitely worked before. (And yes, I copied that working code over directly.)
- My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433570/not-rendering-controls-in-debug-mode), however, my form is not a child of another dialog, and does not live within a parent UI thread.

Answer (score 36):

As much as I try to avoid building unit tests that use `System.Windows.Forms`, I ran into an odd case where I needed this as well and solved it by handling the `Load` event and explicitly setting `Visible = true`. This forces the form to visible when ShowDialog is called from the test method.

```
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // To support calling ShowDialog from test method...
    this.Visible = true;
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, just observe the form instance from your test method and do the same there instead. At least this mitigates the issue further in that it keeps the hack out of your form's code.

```
var frm = new Form1();
frm.Load += (sender, e) => (sender as Form1).Visible = true;
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I had a rare case of needing this and your answer helped. However I realised that I can just create the form object in the test then set myform.visible = true in the test. Works perfectly :)

Comment: The code like David presented worked fine for me on VS2013. However on VS2015 it stopped showing the form. Thank you very much, the lambda helped.

Comment: This fixed it for me on VS2017, where this became an issue after a VS crash

Comment: This fixed it for me when an update to ReSharper seemingly started causing this behavior.

Comment: And here's a ReSharper Issue I created for it if you want to comment there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468681

Comment: what in the world? Some of the dialogs work and some don't. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using VS2017, setting the property `ShowInTaskbar` as `false` did the trick.

This is the complete code used to show the dialog:

```
form.TopMost = true;
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
form.ShowInTaskbar = false;
form.ShowDialog();
```

P.S. After finding this, I've seen the same solution in [Displaying Windows Forms inside unit test methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777804/displaying-windows-forms-inside-unit-test-methods)