# Displaying Windows Forms inside unit test methods

Tags: winforms, unit-testing

I just discovered unit test projects in Visual Studio .NET and am using test methods to set up examples of global code I have developed.

Some global methods involve displaying reusable dialogs like a date-picker and input box. Trouble is, sometimes forms will display and sometimes they won't.

I thought it was related to modality, because I have a report preview form that can be shown modally or non-modally. When I show that non-modally, it does not display. When I show it modally, it does.

Trying my input box never works:

```
string input = "";
using (InputBox box = new InputBox(Title, Prompt, Default))
{
    DialogResult result = box.ShowDialog();
    input = box.txtInput.Text.Trim();
}
return input;
```

Execution stops at the "box.ShowDialog()" line, and at that point I can inspect box and see that its dimensions, location, and visibility are all properly configured -- yet I cannot see the form. I've got to cancel the test to stop everything.

I'd love to use a unit testing project to act as a playground and showcase of existing code, but it seems very limited if I can't display certain forms. I realize this is not really what unit testing is meant for, but I hoped I could build a fun little sandbox this way to help get my developers up to speed.

Comment: A dialog requires an owner window, pretty unlikely it will find a good one in a unit test.  Minimize windows until you find it back.  Don't use dialogs in a unit test.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Fair point -- except several dialogs do work correctly, every time. I have a date chooser and date range chooser, for example, that always display correctly. But then I have an input box form where ShowDialog() pauses execution and the form never displays. Why would there be a difference between the two ShowDialog calls, or the forms being displayed?

Comment: Hans, if you can, please use your comment as the answer -- you got me on the right path. The difference between the forms was that one was instantiated as purely code-driven class while the ones that worked were created as Windows Forms files and summoned via a wrapper method to display them and get data back. When I converted my input box to an actual Windows Form, then I can get it to display. Must have something to do with how forms are displayed when pure classes vs. real "forms" (not sure why!). Still pretty strange...

Comment: Don't use dialogs in a unit test.  I can't write an answer that says more than that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Hans, but I am starting to think you didn't read my post...  I am not really using a unit test for unit testing -- I am using it to place code snippets in a "sandbox" type place. If you know of a better way to "play" in C#, I'm all ears. I come from a Foxpro environment where I learned the most from Foxpro's Command Window (much like Python's "idle"). So, if that is your answer, it isn't really helpful to me (unless you know of another way I can make a playground for my examples and to play with new ideas...). Besides, I figured out how to make it work.

Comment: @sutekh137 Sounds like you're looking for a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).  You can find one in Visual Studio 2015 under View -> Other Windows -> [C# Interactive](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window).  Mono also provides an [Interactive Shell](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/).

Comment: @piedar That is very interesting! Thanks for the great comment with links, and I was able to load a DLL, apply a "using" and have one of my forms display...  I still like the convenient of using test methods, but I could also just use the interactive shell with snippets if I wanted to go in that direction. Thanks for the tip! If you would like to post this as an answer, I would definitely accept it...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally had some consistent success (and lack thereof) based on a single form property: **ShowInTaskbar**.

When a form had that property set to true, such forms would NOT display from a unit test method. When that property is false, all forms display. So, here are the rules as far as I know them to make sure a form can display from a unit test:

- The form should be created as a standard Windows Form item in the project.
- The form should have its ShowInTaskbar property set to FALSE.
- The form needs to be displayed modally (i.e. with ShowDialog()).

This has let me display and test all of my utility forms like date selectors and login screens.

Comment: 3 years later and this fixed my issue, much appreciated!

Comment: Wow, didn't realize it had been 3 years! Glad it helped, though.  *smile*  Nice to see a response other than, "You shouldn't be using forms in a unit test..."!

Comment: you wouldn't believe the search terms I had to go through to find this solution. For context this was my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414102/show-winform-during-unit-test/43449221#43449221. Most of the articles I found were either "How to unit test winforms" or "how to show a winform" but in a winform application and not a class library.

Comment: The search itself becomes the challenge -- glad you rose to it!

Comment: The requirements in this question seem to be confusing, and that confusion is  amplified by the comments. If you wish to display a form in a unit test, then it is not a unit test (unit tests should not test external code). It may be that you had a semantic problem when discussing this issue in the comments. Are these not functional tests?

Comment: The face when you see this post, say "that's bullshit", you try it, and it works... What the hell is going on on the MSTest's end that this is a valid solution?! I suspected that must be something with the message loop not running in a MSTest environment, but I stand corrected. Thanks you, good sir!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The dialog was blinking visible then disappearing. It was already TopMost, and I tried the other trick of setting it to visible then not visible before showdialog was called, but nothing worked.

Then I checked the other dialog that was working fine and it had ControlBox = true. I tried that, and it worked!

This is definitely applicable to the question.